# Interpretation of coefficients and their confidence intervals in a regression analysis

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients

Note: apologies in advance if this is a duplicate, I didn't find a similar q in my search

Can you compare two independent variables and their confidence intervals in a regression model?

I am running a regression model exploring the effect ethnicity and immigration status has on British identity. I have used White British people as my control group.
[image]

The table shows, for example that their is enough evidence Second Generation Indians have a stronger British Identity than White British people.

But given the confidence intervals. Could I *also* state that Second Generation Indians (with a coefficient between 0.544 and 1.819) have a stronger British identity than First Generation Indians (with a coefficient between -0.357 and 0.417). Or does this go beyond what a regression model should be used for? Should I even interpret coefficients that are not statistically significant?

Comment: Using a separate contrast you can compare First Generation Indians with Second Generation Indians.  Alternatively, you could refit your model using First Generation Indians as the reference group. This will produce a coefficient representing the desired comparison.

Comment: Just a little note: Infinite loglikelihood sounds bad (bottom of your table), you should check if something went wrong during model fitting. Or maybe I am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sould interpret all coefficients in your model, even if they are not significant. But you should interpret them correctly!

In linear regression the hypothesis for each coefficient is that the coefficient has a value of zero in your linear equation. Thus the null hypothesis assumes that your variable is not relevant for explaining your y. If the p-value for this test is high (above 0.1) then we can not reject the hypothesis that the coefficient is different than zero.

This means if you see a high p-value for a coefficient, you should not use the interval of the coefficient and assume an effect on your y. By the way for the non-significant feature you can also observe that the interval ranges from -.357 to .417. This is the reason why this feature is not significant, because we can not tell if the effect on y is negative or positive. This would make interpretation really hard. Imagine what that would mean: 'an increase in education has either a negative or positive effect on income'. That would be hard to understand, right?

But if the variables are significant you can compare coefficients and also compare intervals coming from your linear regression.

Answer (score 0):

It's appropriate to briefly discuss/mention any coefficient's value, but if it's not significant, you have to briefly end any statement with "but it's not significant." It also depends: some readers/audience may wonder why you are discussing a predictor that wasn't significant.  Whereas molecular biology lab directors need to know if a predictor has a p-value that's less than 0.1, so they can determine its biological importance and then consider increasing the sample size if it's biologically meaningful/interesting.  Other audiences will expect you to apply an e.g. Bonferroni correction to all the p-values in a table, by adjusting $\alpha=0.05$ to be $\alpha^* =0.05/\#\mathrm{tests}$.  So while you may see significant predictors in the table, someone in an audience will have already applied the Bonferroni adjustment to your p-values in their head and may see nothing! This latter case is usually what happens for conservative reasons.